# Can we set an expiry date when we share a site with external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, administration, sharing

We have a modern communication site, and we want to share the site with external users >> but we need to expire the invitation to the site after 180 days, is this possible?

So the external users can only access the site for 180 days?

I know that I can set expiry date for anyone link, but in our case we want to set the expiry when sharing the site.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is possible to set the automatic expiration after specific days.

[image]

For more information, follow below documentations:

1. [Manage sharing settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off)
2. [Change the sharing settings for a site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-external-sharing-site)

Comment: but are those settings valid when we share a site? or it is just for sharing documents links ? thanks

Comment: Check 2nd last point in above image, Guest access to **a site or OneDrive**.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my reply helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to SharePoint admin center -> Policies -> Sharing -> More external sharing settings -> Set "Guest access to a site or OneDrive will expire automatically after this many days". If your have set an expiration time for guest access, each guest that you invite to the site or with whom you share individual files and folders will be given access for a certain number of days.

After you have set, you could go to the communication site -> Site permissions -> Guest Expiration to manage.

[image]